Modern glove liners - fabric choices
I've had some silk glove liners for decades, and found them very good for extra warmth with very little weight, bulk, or loss of dexterity. But I've managed to tear them in a way that can't be repaired, so I'm in the market for something new.
The silk ones seem very helpful to put on if my outer gloves (typically thinsulate bike gloves, or ski-style gloves that aren't fully waterproof) have been soaked by rain and wrung out; they really seem to add a fair bit of warmth even when damp.  They're also so thin that touchscreens work while wearing them, despite capacitive touchscreens not having been invented when they were made.
What are the options these days, looking at around 20g for a pair in XL? Is silk still best, or is there something better?

Take a look at polypropylene liners.

Silk are still available, not very expensive and seem to beat others on weight.

@WeatherVane yes, silk look like decent value. But my question is whether  there's something better similarly light. Manufacturers don't often state the weight of a pair, and that's all I've got to compare to (some appear to state a fabric weight, which is OK for comparing between their products, but not to a known pair)

... And polypropylene all seem to be knitted and quite a lot thicker (they look thicker than some of the merino ones I've seen, but I can't be sure)

In the end, I went for silk again.  All the alternatives seemed thicker based on the limited information I could find.
The other materials might be better if you've got room to add bulk and/or aren't concerned with touchscreen navigation.
